# Lua doesn't return my userdata

Tags: c++, lua

I've been having some unexpected issues with my touserdata and newuserdata, the data passed to C++ is not the same that is stored when I create the userdata, below I have all the functions related to the creation and the functions that I'm calling (

I create my avatar with this lua code  avatar = avatar_create("hero1") 
which in c++ is this

```
int LuaObjectFactory::createAvatar(lua_State* L){ 
    auto avatar = new Avatar(lua_tostring(L, 1)); // 0x011afd20
    auto userdata = Util::luaP_newuserdata<Avatar>(L, avatar); // 0x011a4a18
    luaP_getScenes(L)->getActiveScene()->addEntity(avatar); 
    Util::luaP_setmetatable(L, Avatar::lGetMetatable());
    return 1;
}
template<typename T> T** luaP_newuserdata(lua_State* L, T* data){
    T** o = static_cast<T**>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(T*)));
    // Does not copy the data, only remembers reference to it
    *o = data;
    return o;
}

inline void luaP_setmetatable(lua_State* L, const string& metatable){
    luaL_getmetatable(L, &metatable[0]);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
}

template<typename T> T* luaP_touserdata(lua_State* L, int idx){
    return *static_cast<T**>(lua_touserdata(L, idx));
}
```

then later on I try to call a function of Avatar's with this lua code

```
avatar = avatar_create("hero1") 
avatar:setPosition(12, 10)
avatarPos = avatar:getPosition()
```

which calls these two functions

```
template<typename T> static int lGetPosition(lua_State* L){
    auto p = Util::luaP_touserdata<T>(L, 1); // 0x008ff0d8
    auto v = p->getPosition();
    lua_pushnumber(L, v.x);
    lua_pushnumber(L, v.y);
    return 0;
}

template<typename T> static int lSetPosition(lua_State* L){
    auto p = Util::luaP_touserdata<T>(L, 1); // 0x008ff0d8
    auto v = Math::Vector2(static_cast<int>(lua_tonumber(L, 2)),
        static_cast<int>(lua_tonumber(L, 3)));
    p->setPosition(v);
    return 0;
}
```

I commented the memory addresses returned from on of my attempts of debugging, the luaP_touserdata returns the same address, although even so the values that I set on 0x008ff0d8 have been erased when I go to get them later

Something else I noticed is that the address of 0x008ff0d8 is a pointer to a pointer which points back to 0x008ff0d8.

Comment: Could you check (using `lua_gettop()`) the number of Lua stack elements after the `Util::luaP_newuserdata<Avatar>` call and after the `Util::luaP_setmetatable` call in `LuaObjectFactory::createAvatar`? The implementation of `Util::luaP_touserdata<T>` might also be relevant ...

Comment: After new Avatar the stack returns 1, after newuserdata the stack returns 2 and after setmetatable the stack returns 3, I added the code to setmetatable above

Comment: Then add a `lua_pop(L, 1);` before the `return 1;`. Somewhere between `luaP_newuserdata` and the `return 1` a new element is pushed to the stack (the `luaP_setmetatable` function looks ok, I suspect `luaP_getScenes`). This element is returned to Lua instead of your userdata.

Comment: I actually just found that out for myself after looking in the function that luaP_getScenes calls, I expected lua_touserdata to return and remove from stack, which it does not.

The pointer is now correct, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using a dedicated binding layer, such as [luabridge](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html) or [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html)? The low level problems you're struggling with in spaghetti code are effectively solved in many binding libraries.

There are even some that use modern c++, such as [Selene](https://github.com/jeremyong/Selene) and [LuaGlue](https://github.com/Tomasu/LuaGlue)
or [luawrapper](https://github.com/Tomaka17/luawrapper) and [luapp11](https://github.com/balkamm/luapp11)